# Is it possible, normal but not regular?

Tags: general-topology

I know "**every normal space is regular space**". But today, while practicing some problem I saw the following,

Let $X=\{a, b,c\}$ and $τ=\{ ∅, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}, X\}$ be a topology on $X$.

Clearly I can see, for $a∈X$ and closed set $\{c\}$ there **does not** exists  disjoint open sets  $U$, $V$ such that $a∈U$ and $\{c\}⊆V$ and hence $X$ is not regular. So it must be not normal!

But what I saw in key that, $X$ is normal! How it's possible? How $X$ is normal? Please help me...

Comment: It is a matter of definitions. See wikipedia articles

Comment: Yeah, that's crazy. :)

Comment: @user126154 sir, already checked it but, as a beginner in topology, there is not "enough information" "**for me**" to understand this...:-(

Comment: in your example points are not closed ($T_1$ spaces), a condition which is often required in definitions

Comment: Sir, could you please elaborate, "how the space is normal, though it's not regular. Further, isn't condition that you told, is required for $T_1$ ?

Comment: The proof that I know is that "normal and $T_1$ implies regular". Your space is Normal just because closed sets are $\{\emptyset, X,\{c\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}\}$ and so there are no two disjoint non-empty closed sets.

Comment: Maybe your text that says normal implies regular means the $T_4$ implies $T_3$ implication, as I explain below. plain normal need not imply plain regular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your space $X$ the closed sets are $\{X, \{b,c\}, \{a,c\}, \{c\},\emptyset\}$ (the complements of the open sets).

This means there are **no** pairs of non-empty closed disjoint sets. So **voidly** (there is nothing to do) $X$ is normal.

But as you rightly say you cannot separate the point $a$ from the closed set $\{c\}$ (as the only open set containing $c$ is $X$, e.g.), so $X$ is not regular.

It's common to have a combination of $T_1$ with either normality or regularity. This is done, because then, as $T_1$ is equivalent to the fact that all singletons $\{x\}$ are closed, we are sure that there are actually lots of pairs of non-empty disjoint closed sets and pairs of points and closed sets such that we can apply the regularity and normality. In particular, in both cases we know that $X$ is Hausdorff: separating points $x \neq y$ can also be seen as separating the closed sets $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ or the point $x$ and the closed set $\{y\}$, say.

If we have $X$ that $T_1$ and normal, then we can separate all points $x\in X$ and $C \subseteq X$ closed with $x \notin C$, because we just separate the pair of (disjoint) closed sets $\{x\}$ and $C$ by normality and use those open sets.
So then $X$ is $T_1$ and regular.

If you want to be really subtle, note that $X$ $T_0$ and regular already implies that $X$ is $T_1$ (and thus $T_2$ as we saw): let $x \neq y$. By $T_0$ we have that there either is an open subset $O$ such that $x \in O, y \notin O$ or the other way round. First case: define $C= X\setminus O$ which is closed such that $x \notin C$, so regularity gives us that there are disjoint open sets $U_x$ and $V$ such that $x \in U_x$ and $y \in X\setminus O \subseteq V$.
But then $V$ is an open subset that contains $y$ but not $x$, so completing the proof of $T_1$-ness. The second case is similar, interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$. Note that normal plus $T_0$ need not imply $T_1$ as witnessed by the Sierpinski space, e.g.

The combination of $X$ being regular and $T_1$ (or $T_0$) is usually called $T_3$ (the $T$ stands for German "Trennungsaxiom" (separation axiom) and for normality plus $T_1$ we have $T_4$ as a shorthand. Beware that some texts use $T_3$ for just plain regular, etc. Always check such things to avoid confusion. Or the combination is called "regular" etc. I'm in favour of using the $T_3, T_4$ for the strengthened versions, because then $T_j \Rightarrow T_i$ when $j > i$.

Answer (score 0):

If NORMAL and REGULAR are both defined without requiring T1, then normal does NOT imply regular (and, of course, vice versa).  The above example works, as does any nontrivial space whose open sets are a chain under containment:  There are no disjoint closed sets OR open sets. The former makes the space vacuously normal; but regularity fails due the existence of a closed set and an excluded point.